# Terminology : encoding without decoding?

Tags: encryption, encoding

I am having trouble understanding such basic concept.

I did some research about cryptography and manipulated few concepts (RSA key pair, AES/DES/whatever secret key, hash functions ...). But I would like to understand more deeply one basic thing :

Encoding is transforming a message into an other form.
Decoding is giving a message its original form.
Well, for me it sounds like encryption is encoding. And I think (please correct me) that encrytion is a way of encoding (for a very particular purpose : increasing the confidence of having a known list of person who can decode).

But what about hash function ? Since there is no decoding function, when we hash a message, can we say :

"this text is this message **encoded** with SHA-1 algorithm",

as we can surely say :

"this digest is this message **hashed** with SHA-1 algorithm"  ?

Thank you !

Comment: You're mixing Encoding and Encryption.

Comment: And No, you cannot Encrypt with SHA-1. You can Hash it.

Comment: In which sense am I mixing encoding and encryption ? Because for me encoding is a set of methods that includes (but is not limited to) the set of encryptions methods.

I know I cannot "encrypt" with sha-1, but can I "encode" ?

Comment: Maybe a more general question :

Can we talk about encoding if there is no decoding function that allows to recover the original message ?

Comment: Check out what `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` can do for you. That will be an answer.

Comment: *"Can we talk about encoding if there is no decoding function"* – no, that's merely a shredder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Encoding*, and its reverse *decoding*, are mere transformations of the data into some alternative form. Each form expresses the exact same data, just written differently. The transformation is well known and can be carried out by anyone.

*Encryption*, and its reverse *decryption*, is the encoding of data using a *secret*. The ciphertext (the encrypted data), is for all intents and purposes random noise. The ciphertext does not express the plaintext in some alternative format, the plaintext is *hidden inside* the ciphertext. The transformation is *not well known*, as it requires a secret key which, supposedly, only specific entities are in possession of.

In that way, yes, encryption is a specialised form of encoding, but in usage "encoding" typically means a transformation that can be carried out by anyone, while "encryption" specifically involves preventing unauthorised parties from carrying out the transformation.

*Hashing* is a one-way operation (there's no *dehashing*) and thereby entirely distinct from the other two operations.

Comment: From your last sentence, I assume that the answer to my question is "no" ?

Thank you for taking the time to write, although it might not be clear in my question, everything you stated was quite clear in my head.

Comment: Indeed, no: any *"en-"* implies a *"de-"*, which in the case of SHA-1 doesn't exist.

Comment: Then "enlightening" does not exist ? Sad, I was thinking of this adjective for your global answers.

Thank you again !

Comment: Since there's no delightening… no.